# Numpy Polynomial class not printing correct coefficients from fit

Tags: python, numpy

As recommended in the numpy documentation, I am trying to move from the old `polyfit` and `polyval` functions to the `Polynomial` class. Below is a minimal example that demonstrates my confusion with this.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-2.3, -2.8, -2.9, -3.1])
y = np.array([2.4, 3.1, 3.3, 3.5])

poly = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1)
print(poly)
print(poly.coef)
print(poly(0))
print(poly(1) - poly(0))
```

which gives the output, running numpy 1.23.3,

```
2.9697841726618703 - 0.5611510791366912·x¹
[ 2.96978417 -0.56115108]
-0.8179856115107942
-1.4028776978417268
```

Judging from the first two lines, the fitted polynomial is something like 2.969 - 0.561x. But evaluating it at x=0 gives -0.817, and evaluating the slope by f(1) - f(0) gives -1.40. The latter is what I would expect given the points that I am fitting, but what's going on with the first two lines of output?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial) you'll see that the polynomial object has two more fields: `poly.domain` and `poly.window`.
To get better numerical properties the range independent variable of the input to `fit()` will get renormalized to `[-1, 1]` (by default at least, this is the `poly.window` you can set yourself), so the coefficients you get from `poly.coef` are valid on that renormalized domain. To get back the "original" coefficients you have to undo that normalization, just as I've done in the following snippet. You can also go in the other direction an normalize the x-values yourself which I also included in this snippet:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(t, c[0] + c[1]*t)  # line in the normalized domain
#x_normalized = (x - d[0])/(d[1] - d[0]) * 2 - 1  # points in the normalized domain
a = 2/(d[1]-d[0])
b = - 2*d[0]/(d[1]-d[0]) - 1
x_normalized = a*x + b
print('original coefficients')
print(a*c[1], c[1]*b + c[0])
plt.plot(x_normalized, y, 'o')
plt.show()
```